# MathJax fails to load in the comments

Tags: discussion, mathjax, comment, firefox

Starting few days ago MathJax fails to load in the comments. It works well in the other boxes: questions and answers. 
Used browser: Mozilla.

However this phenomenon doesn't occur when I use Chrome.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Same issue here.